# How to find out how long a process has been running for?

Tags: windows, wmic, windows-server-2012

Is it possible to use `wmic` or `powershell` to find out how long a process has been running for?

If not, is there any other mean to obtain this information from Windows OS?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `New-TimeSpan –Start`; passing the `StartTime` property of the process which you want to know how long has been running. Here an example which shows how long `notepad` has been running:

```
PS C:\> New-TimeSpan -Start (get-process notepad).StartTime


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 2
Milliseconds      : 920
Ticks             : 29200041
TotalDays         : 3.379634375E-05
TotalHours        : 0.00081111225
TotalMinutes      : 0.048666735
TotalSeconds      : 2.9200041
TotalMilliseconds : 2920.0041
```

Comment: And to do this by process id: `New-TimeSpan -Start (get-process -id 4).StartTime`, you may have to be an admin to get this information for some processes.

Comment: Kept getting conversion errors so switched to syntax `(Get-Process notepad).StartTime | % {New-TimeSpan -Start $_}` to get by on Server 2012 R2. What an old server this is!